# Ping 8.8.8.8 from VM in Azure: Windows 2008 Server

Tags: azure, windows-server-2008, vpn, ping

In Amazon Web Services, if I create a VM Instance with Windows 2008 Server, I can ping to 8.8.8.8 without changing any setting.

In Azure, instead, I created a VM with Windows 2008 Server and can't ping 8.8.8.8:

> ping 8.8.8.8
>
> Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
> Request timed out.
> Request timed out.
> Request timed out.
> Request timed out.

**How can I allow pinging?** I enabled in the firewall's inbounds this setting:
File and printer sharing (Echo request - ICMPv4-In)

But didn't work.

Also: **how can I ping an IP that is in the same "virtual network" (VPN)?**

Answer (score 1):

The outgoing  ICMP to internet from Azure VMs is not supported.

Comment: Seriously? And how can I test that my VM is capable of reaching a computer living in the same VPN? (site-to-site VPN)

Comment: In this case, ICMP is no problems. However, ICMP may be rejected by your VPN router. Does allow routing of ICMP by your VPN router settings?